# clustering algorithm for non-dimensional data

Tags: machine-learning, lg.learning, clustering

i have a dataset of thousands of points and a means of measuring the distance between any two points, but the data points have no dimensionality. i want an algorithm to find cluster centers in this dataset. i imagine that because the data has no dimensions, a cluster center might consist of several data points and a tolerance, and membership within the cluster might be determined by the average of the distance of a data point to every data point in the cluster center.

please forgive me if this question has a well known solution, i know very little about this kind of problem! my (very limited) research has only turned up clustering algorithms for dimensional data, but i apologize in advance if i've missed something obvious.

thank you!

Comment: Why does non-dimensionality make this problem special?

Comment: Some algorithms I saw for clustering (really just k-means) require generation of random data points as seeds, which is not possible with dimensionless data. So, the special requirement is that the cluster centers must be represented by a set of existing data points (perhaps weighted).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If the distance function is a metric, then you can employ either $k$-center clustering (where the maximum radius of a ball is minimized) or $k$-median clustering (which minimizes the sum of distances to cluster centers). $k$-center clustering is easy: merely pick the $k$-farthest points, and you're guaranteed to get a 2-approximation via triangle inequality (this is an old result due to Gonzalez).

For $k$-median clustering, there's been a ton of work, too much to review here. Michael Shindler at UCLA [has a nice survey](http://www.cs.ucla.edu/~shindler/shindler-kMedian-survey.pdf) of the main ideas.

Both these problems are NP-hard in general, and are hard to approximate to within an arbitrary factor. Note that if you drop the condition of being a metric, things get a lot worse in terms of approximability.

Another, more heuristic approach which might be ok for your application is to use a technique like MDS (multidimensional scaling) to embed your distance matrix in a Euclidean space, and then use one of many different Euclidean clustering methods (or even $k$-means clustering). If you are sure that your distance function is a metric, then you can do a slightly more intelligent embedding into Euclidean space and get a provable (albeit weak) guarantee on the quality of your answer.

Ultimately, as with most clustering problems, your final choice depends on the application, your data size, and so on.

Comment: Thank you for the quick & clear overview. It will take me at least a few days to determine if you have answered my question. It seems I have a lot to learn before I understand my problem sufficiently :)

Answer (score 5):

There's also [correlation clustering](http://geomblog.blogspot.com/2009/08/correlation-clustering-i-dont-like-you.html), which has as input information for each pair of items indicating whether they belong in either the same cluster or different clusters.

Comment: yes, that's another good example. And of course Warren is an expert on this ! I don't know if the OP's input was +/- though, or could be converted via thresholding. if so, this is definitely a viable option.

Answer (score 5):

If you're just looking for good empirical performance, the affinity propagation algorithm usually works better than k-medians.  There is code available in several languages and publications describing the algorithm in more detail are here:
http://www.psi.toronto.edu/index.php?q=affinity%20propagation

The objective that it tries to maximize is:
$$\sum_{i} s(i, c_i)$$

where $s$ is a similarity measure defined between pairs of points (e.g., negative distance), and $c_i \in \mathbf{c}$ gives the cluster that $i$ belongs to.  There is one additional parameter given in $s(i, i)$ that controls whether you prefer large or small clusters.

Answer (score 5):

Your question seems to imply that you are looking for an algorithm with decent computational time.  Given the size of your vertices (or points) would be to create a weighted graph representation of your data and use Markov Cluster Algorithm (MCL) to cluster the graph.

http://www.micans.org/mcl/

MCL is based on random walks through weighted and unweighted graphs to find dense subgraphs. It is able to handle large graphs and has been used in many well-known, well-used bioinformatic programs (such as BLAST). -Boucher

Answer (score 1):

Consider [k-nearest neighbour algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-nearest_neighbor_algorithm).

Comment: Raphael, the k-NN algorithm is not really a clustering algorithm, is it ? unless you repeatedly pull out the k neighbors of a node ?

Comment: We draw an edge between nodes that are in each other's sets of $k$ nearest nodes. In the resulting graph, cliques (almost-cliques) should be some kind of cluster. I figured that since we are building up the graph, identifying these cliques should not be too hard, but I did not think it through completely.